# using a variable name in my VBA sumif formula

Tags: vba

I have built a code that performs a sumif on another workbook that I open using the get open filename dialogue box. I intend to use this formula daily, and hence the workbook where I intend to obtain the information and the workbook where I intend to paste the results will continue to have varying names basing on the date of the day.
I get a type mismatch on the SUMIF formula. Please help.

```
Sub flextab()

Dim LastCol As Integer, LastRow As Long
 ' Get the dimensions
With Sheets("Flex")
     LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
    'Insert a column where required.
   Cells(2, LastCol - 1).EntireColumn.Insert
   'Insert the date
   Cells(2, LastCol - 1).Value = Date - 1

'Insert the balance sheet balances for the day
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim FileName1 As String, FileName2 As String
Dim BalSheet As Worksheet
Dim Ret1

FileName1 = ThisWorkbook.Name

   '~~> Get the first File
Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
, "Please select the Balance sheet for the day")
If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)
FileName2 = wb2.Name

Workbooks(FileName1).Activate

      'let's get a reference to the worksheet with the source values
Set BalSheet = Workbooks(FileName2).Worksheets("Sheet1")

 With Worksheets("Flex").Range(Cells(5, LastCol - 1), Cells(109, LastCol - 1))
    'let's put in our SUMIF formulas
    .Formula = "=SUMIF(" & BalSheet.Range("B2:B20000") & "," & Worksheets("Flex").Range("A5") & " , " & BalSheet.Range("n2:n20000") & ")"

    'let's convert the formulas into values
    .Value = .Value
End With
     wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set wb2 = Nothing
Set wb1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding ranges to a string, while ranges are objects. Try this:

```
"=SUMIF(" & BalSheet.Range("B2:B20000").Address & "," & Worksheets("Flex").Range("A5").Value & " , " & BalSheet.Range("n2:n20000").Address & ")"
```

instead of this:

```
"=SUMIF(" & BalSheet.Range("B2:B20000") & "," & worksheets("Flex").Range("A5") & " , " & BalSheet.Range("n2:n20000") & ")"
```

You are working with 2 workbooks, but you are using some worksheets without qualifier.

If you have focus to the wrong workbook this will fail if the workbook that is active does not have a Flex worksheet.

So change this:
    Worksheets("Flex").Range(Cells(5, LastCol - 1)

to this:

```
wbX.Worksheets("Flex").Range(Cells(5, LastCol - 1)
```

where the X is the correct workbook.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks the procedure worked. The only issue now is that it returns a value of zero. Might there be a reason why this is happening.

Comment: I looked at the SUMIF a little closer, the second parameter you do not need the range, but the value of the A5 cell. If you change the following 

    Worksheets("Flex").Range("A5").Address

To:

     Worksheets("Flex").Range("A5").Value

you should be good.

Comment: With wb1.Worksheets("Flex").Range(Cells(5, LastCol - 1), Cells(109, LastCol - 1))
    'let's put in our SUMIF formulas
    .Formula = "=SUMIF(" & BalSheet.Range("B2:B20000").Address & "," & Worksheets("Flex").Range("A5").Value & ", " & BalSheet.Range("N2:N20000").Address & ")"
    'let's convert the formulas into values
    .Value = .Value
End With

Comment: Hi Steve I have updated it as shown above but it still brings back zeros